# Python: How do I get this function to print?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#integers to be input
n = input('Enter \"n\" trials')
x = input('Enter \"x\" number of succeses')
p = input('Enter the probability \"p\" of success on a single trial')

#Probability Distribution function
def probDist(n, x, p):
    q = (1-p)**(n-x)
    numerator = math.factorial(n);
    denominator = math.factorial(x)* math.factorial(n-x);
    C = numerator / denominator;
    answer = C*p**x*q;

    return answer

# Does this have to come after I define the function? Or does this matter in Python
# Also this part just doesn't work.
dist = probDist(n, x, p);
print(dist);
```

Here's the error that I get after I run and I input all the values.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 17, in <module>
    dist = probDist(n, x, p);
  line 9, in probDist
    q = (1-p)**(n-x)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `input` *always* returns a string, without applying `eval` the the user input. Python 2.x `input` does `eval`, but that's rarely what you want. If you want an integer, use `int(input(...))` and if you want a float (not quite the same as a real number, as it has only limited range!), use `float(input)`. (You should propably catch `ValueError` to handle the cases where the input is not appropiate; if this is for exercise/education, it's propably okay to leave error handling out for now.)

Answer (score 2):

> Does this have to come after I define the function?

Yes.

> q = (1-p)**(n-x)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

You have two `-` operations.  One of those two is a mixture of `int` and `str` data.

Let's go through each operand.

1 - int

p - result of `input()`, and therefore a string

n - result of `input()`, and therefore a string

x - result of `input()`, and therefore a string

You probably want to do something to convert the results of `input()` to a proper floating-point value.  `float()` works well for this.